# Infinite-dimensional Bregman divergence

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, convex-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Let $C$ be a convex subset of $\mathbb R^n$ with nonempty interior. Let $f: C \to \mathbb R$ be a strictly convex function, differentiable in the interior of $C$, whose gradient $\nabla f$ extends to a bounded, continuous function on $C$. The *Bregman divergence* $d_f$ for $f$ is defined for all $x,y \in C$ by
$$d_f(x,y) = f(x) - f(y) - \nabla f(x) \cdot(y-x).$$

> I am wondering if this definition has been extended to infinite-dimensional spaces. In particular, how would one define a Bregman divergence in an arbitrary (locally convex) topological vector space? I would appreciate references but welcome all ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a pretty great monograph on the subject; I've been told it is "the" reference for modern Bregman divergence theory, at least from an optimization/monotone-operator viewpoint. Note that they remain in a Banach space for most of their results, so infinite dimensions are fair game. They sometimes specialize to a Hilbert space, which also can be infinite dimensional. They do a good job of noting when the finite-dimensional setting provides simpler results.

> H. H. Bauschke, J. M. Borwein, and P. L. Combettes, Bregman monotone optimization algorithms, *SIAM Journal on Control and Optimization*, vol. 42, no. 2, pp. 596-636, June 2003.

Preprint is available, e.g., [here](https://pcombet.math.ncsu.edu/sicon2.pdf).

Comment: Thanks! I’ll have a look at it.

Comment: Yep, this looks like exactly the sort of thing I was hoping for. Thanks again!

Comment: @grndl happy to help!